# File integrity is occasionally compromised after being transferred via Wifi / ssh with with scp and rsync

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, rsync, scp, wifi-transfer

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that I use as a media server (with Plex). The RPi3 is connected to my home LAN both via WiFi and via Ethernet cable. I use the WiFi to transfer files from my laptop to the RPi3 and the Ethernet to stream to the TV.

I started using the RPi3 with Plex a few weeks ago and I immediately noticed that the TV Plex app had issues with some video files. At first, I thought that the problem was with Plex (either on the server side or with the TV app side) or with the TV decoding of video files: a few video files were working fine, other crashed, desynced the audio track at some point or lost the audio altogether. But when I tried moving the problematic file back to the laptop I finally noticed that also VLC had issues playing the file.

So I did a few experiments by checking the validity of files *after* transferring them via SSH with `scp` and `rsync`, from the laptop to the RPi3 with `sha1sum`. And in about 50% of the cases, the hash did not match. This didn't seem to depend on the actual file since I was actually able to transfer correctly after a few attempts.

What could cause the integrity problem?

Comment: memory/blockdevice error.

Comment: @IporSircer Can you develop?